# Is it theoretically possible to emulate a human brain on a computer?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Our brain consists of billions of neurons which basically work with all the incoming data from our senses, handle our consciousness, emotions and creativity as well as our hormone system, etc.

So I'm completely new to this topic but doesn't each neuron have a fixed function? E.g.: If a signal of strength x enters, if the last signal was x ms ago, redirect it.

From what I've learned in biology about our nerves system which includes our brain because both consist of simple neurons, **it seems to me as our brain is one big, complicated computer**.

Maybe so complicated that things such as intelligence and cognition become possible?

As the most complicated things about a neuron pretty much are the chemical aspects on generating an electric singal, keeping itself alive, and eventually segmenting itself, it should be pretty easy emulating some on a computer, or?
You won't have to worry about keeping your virtual neuron alive, or?

- If you can emulate a **single** neuron on a computer, which shouldn't be too hard, could you theoretically emulate more than 1000 billions of them, recreating intelligence, cognition and maybe even creativity?

In my question I'm leaving out the following aspects:

- Speed of our current (super) computers
- Actually writing a program for emulating neurons

I don't know much about this topic, please tell me if I got anything wrong :)

(My secret goal: Make a copy of my brain and store it on some 10 million TB HDD and make someone start it up in the future)

Comment: @Matthew: You can perfectly emulate all aspects of an analog computer with a digital one?

Comment: Huge philosophical problem: we haven't really decided what "consciousness, emotions and creativity" are. Thus, you have a pretty vague benchmark.

Somewhat large technical problem: you might need quite a lot of computing power to run a simulation. Doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: @JoelK: No, you cannot perfectly emulate an analog computer with a digital one.  Digital is finite values and low signal to noise, analog is infinite values and higher signal to noise.  You can produce close examples and simulations but they will never be 100% the same.  Even with 1024bit width processors the resolution per unit of data in a digital system could not compare to analog.  And the digital would have a more stable form leading to less random interactions that induce evolution and mutations.

Answer (score 5):

A neuron-like circuit can be built with a handful of transistors.  Let's say it takes about a dozen transistors on average.  (See http://diwww.epfl.ch/lami/team/vschaik/eap/neurons.html for an example.)

A brain-sized circuit would require 100 billion such neurons (more or less).

That's 1.2 trillion transistors.

A quad-core Itanium has 2 billion transistors.

You'd need a server rack with 600 quad-core processors to be brain-sized.  Think $15M US to purchase the servers.  You'll need power management and cooling plus real-estate to support this mess.

One significant issue in simulating the brain is scale.  The actual brain only dissipates a few watts.  Power consumption is 3 square meals per day.  A pint of gin.  Maintenance is 8 hours of downtime.  Real estate is a 42-foot sailboat (22 Net Tons of volume as ships are measured) and a place to drop the hook.

A server cage with 600 quad-core processors uses a lot more energy, cooling and maintenance.  It would require two full-time people to keep this "brain-sized" server farm running.

It seems simpler to just teach the two people what you know and skip the hardware investment.

Comment: Whilst this answer is obviously true, he specifically left out hardware limitations and was talking theoretically. Plus we all know that yesterdays building sized computers can now fit in the palm of your hand...

Comment: You are forgetting that the transistors in digital processors are configured for switching and more than one transistor is used per gate.  The closest you could do to a real neural network with transistors would be to build operation amplifiers that would be ganged together.  This would probably multiple your number of required transistors by at least 20.

Comment: @Robin Day: While true, one issue is scale.  The brain is compact, fast, and highly optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Roger Penrose presents the argument that human consciousness  is non-algorithmic, and thus is not capable of being modeled by a conventional Turing machine-type of digital computer. If it's like that you can forget about building a brain with a computer...

Comment: Penrose's arguments are included in his book "The Emperor's New Mind": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Mind

Answer (score 3):

Simulating a neuron is possible and therefore theoretically simulating a brain is possible.

The two things that always stump me as an issue is input and output though.

We have a very large number of nerve endings that all provide input to the brain. Without them the brain is useless. How can we simulate something as complicated as the human brain without also simulating the entire human body!?!

Output, once the brain has "dealt" with all of the inputs that it gets, what is then the output from it? How could you say that the "copy" of your brain was actually you without again hooking it up to a real human body that could speak and tell you?

All in all, a fascinating subject!!!!

Comment: Plus the non--neural things that appear to influence behavior -- the whole endocrine system may be part of what we experience as "consciousness".  How much of that is influenced by the biota living in our gut?  Does "gut feeling" have an actual biological basis?  If so, then brain is only one small part of what we are.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [Blue Brain Project](http://bluebrain.epfl.ch/) is getting close, and I believe Moore's Law has a $1000 computer getting there by 2049.

The main issue is that our brains are based largely on controlling a human body, which means that our language comprehension and production, the basis of our high-level reasoning and semantic object recognition, is strongly tied to its potential and practiced outputs to a larynx, tongue, and face muscles. Further, our reward systems are tied to signals that indicate sustenance and social approval, which are not the goals we generally want a brain-based AI to have.

An exact simulation of the human brain will be useful in studying the effects of drugs and other chemicals, but I think that the next steps will be in isolating pathways that let us do things that are hard for computers (e.g. visual system, fusiform gyrus, face recognition), and developing new or modifying known structures for representing concepts.

Answer (score 2):

The key problem with simulating neural networks (and human brain is a neural network) is that they function continuously, while digital computers function in cycles. So in a neural network different neurons function independently in parallel while in a computer you only simulate discrete system states.

That's why adequately simulating real neural networks is very problematic at the moment and we're very far from it.

Comment: Some research suggests we *do* have an internal clock: http://thefutureofthings.com/news/8443/internal-brain-wave-clock.html I could cite better if I weren't lazy.

Comment: programs can also run in parallel and cores can run at different clocks. The problem is having enough of them on chip and yet have it be cost and computationally efficient.

Comment: As long as your "cycle" is small enough then anything can be deemed to function "continuously". It could, for example, be considered that the entire universe is tied to the "pulse" of a quark.

Answer (score 2):

**Short:** yes we will surely be able to reproduce artificial brains, but no it maybe won't be with our current computers models (Turing machines), because we simply don't know yet enough about the brain to know if we need new computers (super-Turing or biologically engineered brains) or if current computers (with more power/storage space) are enough to simulate a whole brain.

---

**Long:**

Disclaimer: I am working in computational neuroscience research and I am interested both by the neurobiological side and the computational (artificial intelligence) side.

Most of the answers assume as true OP's postulate that simulating neurons is enough to save the whole brain state and thus simulate a whole brain.

**That's not true.**

The brain is more than just neurons.

First, there is the connectivity, the synapses, that is of paramount importance, even maybe more than neurons.

Secondly, there are glial cells such as astrocytes and oligodendrocytes that also possess their own connectivity and communication system.

Thirdly, neurons are heterogenous, which means that there is not just one template model of a neuron that we could just scale up to the required amount to simulate a brain, we also have to define multiple types of neurons and place them pertinently at the right places. Plus, the types can be continuous, so in fact you can have neurons that are half way between 3 different types...

Fourthly, we don't know much about the rules of brain's information processing and management. Sure, we discovered that the cerebellum works pretty much like an artificial neural network using stochastic gradient descent, and that the dopaminergic system works like TD-learning, but then we have no clue about the rest of the brain, even memory is out of reach (although we guess it's something close to a Hopfield network, but there's no precise model yet).

Fifthly, there are so many other examples from current research in neurobiology and computational neuroscience showing the complexity of brain's objects and networks dynamics that this list can go on and on.

So in the end, your question cannot be answered, because we simply do not know yet enough about the brain to know if our current computers (Turing machines) are enough to reproduce the complexity of biological brains to give rise to the full spectrum of cognitive functions.

However, biology field is getting closer and closer to computer science field, as you can see with biologically engineered viruses and cells that are programmed pretty much like you develop a computer program, and genetical therapies that basically re-engineer a living system based on its "class" template (the genome). So I dare to say that once we know enough about the brain's architecture and dynamics, the in-silico reproduction won't be an issue: if our current computers cannot reproduce the brain because of theoretical constraints, we will devise new computers. And if only biological systems can reproduce the brain, we will be able to program an artificial biological brain (we can already 3D-print functional bladders and skin and veins and hearts etc.).

So I would dare say (even if it can be controversial, this is here my own claim) that **yes, artificial brains will surely be possible someday**, but whether it will be as a Turing machine computer, a super-Turing computer or a biologically engineered brain remain to be seen depending on our progress in the knowledge of brain's mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Researchers far smarter than most recon so, **see [Blue Brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Brain_Project) from IBM and others**.

> The Blue Brain Project is the first
>   comprehensive attempt to
>   reverse-engineer the mammalian brain,
>   in order to understand brain function
>   and dysfunction through detailed
>   simulations.

Theoretically the brain can be modeled using a computer (as software and hard/wetware are compatible or mutually expressible). The question isn't a theoretical one as far as computer science goes, but a *philosophical* one:

> Can we model the (chaotic) way in which a brain develops. Is a brains power it's hardware or the environment that shapes the development and emergent properties of that hardware as it learns

Even more mental:

> If I, with 100% accuracy modeled my own brain, then started the simulation. And that brain had my memories (as it has my brain's physical form) ... is it me? If not, what do I have that it doesn't?

I think that if we are ever in a position to emulate the brain, we should have been working on logical system based on biological principles with better applications than the brain itself.

We all have a brain, and we all have access to it's amazing power already ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are *remotely* close enough to understanding the human brain to even *begin* thinking about replicating it.

Scientists would have you think we are nearly there, but with regards to the brain we're not much further along than Dr. Frankenstein.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to backup those spurious claims?

Comment: @Aiden, even the most cutting edge (publicly available) research into human brain function goes very little to describing how the human brain remembers, learns, imagines or produces varying states of consciousness. We are still a long way from understanding this.

Comment: @Galwegian - a) He is talking about virtual reproduction of the physical (the what) not understanding the how or why. b) Still a lack of quantitative evidence - just subjectivity.

Comment: @Jonners - "Frankenstein's monster" was fictitious, I think Frankenstein was loosely based on a dude.

Comment: @Aiden - you may be thinking of Erasmus Darwin, who was said to have animated dead matter through the use of galvanism. Dr. Frankenstein was a purely ficticious character created by Mary Shelley as the protagonist of a horror story about that general theme.

Answer (score 1):

What is your goal? Do you want a program that can make intelligent decisions or a program that provides a realistic model of how the human brain actually works? Artificial intelligence can be approached from the perspective of psychology, where the goal is to simulate the brain and thereby get a better understanding of how humans think, or from the perspective of mathematics, optimization theory, decision theory, information theory, and computer science, in which case the goal is to create a program that is capable of making intelligent decisions in a computationally efficient manner. The latter, I would say is pretty much solved, although advances are definitely still being made. When it comes to a realistic simulation of the brain, I think we were only recently able to simulate a brain of cat semi-realistically; when it comes to humans, it would not be very computationally feasible at present.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution. Current projects on brain simulation work on a model of a human brain. Your idea about storing your mind on a hard-disk is crazy: if you want a replica of your mind you'll need two things. First, another "blank" brain. Second, **devise a method to perfectly transfer all the information contained in your brain: down to the quantum states of every atom in it**.

Good luck with that :)

EDIT: The dog ate part of my text.

Comment: The secret goal part was ment to be a joke :)

Comment: if we could emulate the brain, your first condition is met -- we have that "blank" brain. That's what's being asked: is it possible to create such a thing.

Comment: I see a stark difference between the processes happening on the human brain and a computer-based simulation of such processes based on some mathematical model which is abstracting a lot of detail. What is useful to predict patterns in the activation of neurons given certain stimuli is not necessarily useful to predict - let alone, replicate - human-like decision making.